# Using %USERNAME% environment variable in Windows batch file with command-line ftp

Tags: batch-file, ftp

```
ftp
open ftp.drivehq.com 
username
password
cd  \wwwhome\Logs\
put "C:\Users\Cody\Desktop\ISO's\mini.iso"
bye
exit
```

How do you use `%USERNAME%` instead of hard-coding `Cody`, when used with `ftp`?

Comment: How are you generating and storing these FTP commands? If you've just hard-coded them in a textfile, yeah, it's not going to work; FTP isn't batch. If you write a batch script to `echo` everything to a text file, it will work.

Comment: I posted the wrong one, this is the hard-coded version, I do have a batch script to echo everything saved.

Comment: I think I'd be tempted to use, `CD .\wwwhome\Logs` or `CD  wwwhome\Logs` instead of `cd  \wwwhome\Logs\ `. I may even be further tempted by considering the **`/D`** option with `CD`.

Comment: may I ask why? trying to learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another batch file solution with code similar to code written by [Martin Prikryl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/850848/martin-prikryl) with three enhancements.

1. `%USERPROFILE%` is used instead of `C:\Users\%username%` which makes this batch file solution work also on Windows XP and on machines on which the user's profile directory is not on drive `C:` or in a different directory than `C:\Users` which is of course possible too.
2. `%SystemRoot%\System32\ftp.exe` is used in the batch file instead of just `ftp` to make this batch file work also if by chance there is an ftp.* file with a file extension listed in environment variable `PATHEXT` in current directory or any other directory in environment variable `PATH` and not being the `ftp` executable in Windows system directory.
3. The ISO file name is renamed before upload with including a random decimal number between 0 and 32767 as asked for with a comment.

The command lines of enhanced batch file:

```
:RandomIsoName
set "RandomName=mini_%RANDOM%.iso"
if exist "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\ISO's\%RandomName%" goto RandomIsoName
ren "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\ISO's\mini.iso" "%RandomName%"

(
echo open hostname
echo username
echo password
echo cd \wwwhome\Logs\
echo put "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\ISO's\%RandomName%"
echo bye
)>ftp.txt
%SystemRoot%\System32\ftp.exe -s:ftp.txt
```

Comment: Also, is there anyway to rename the file as lets say `%random%` after or before the upload?

Answer (score 1):

You have to generate the `ftp` script using that variable:

```
echo open hostname>ftp.txt
echo username>>ftp.txt
echo password>>ftp.txt
echo cd  \wwwhome\Logs\>>ftp.txt
echo put "C:\Users\%username%\Desktop\ISO's\mini.iso">>ftp.txt
echo bye>>ftp.txt
ftp -s:ftp.txt
```

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I accepted your answer without testing the script. For some reason it just keeps overwriting the ftp.txt file repeatedly and never executing `ftp -s:ftp.txt`

Comment: I guess that you named your batch file `ftp.bat`. So the last line re-executes the batch file itself and not the `ftp.exe`.